# searching list of objects

Tags: c#, .net

I have a List of Student objects as such: `List<StudentInfo>`. Now the StudentInfo object has certain parameters such as Name, ID and Attendance. I want to search the list by two things. I want to search by student Name and student id. The query should return the Attendance count for the studentInfo object. Here is what i have tried:

```
return studentInfoList
    .Select((item) => new { value = item })
    .Where(item => item.value.StudentName.Equals(name) 
                   && item.value.StudentID.Equals(id))
    .Select(item => item.value.Attendance);
```

How can i do this?

Comment: If Attendance is a collection, writing item.value.Attendance.Count() should be enough.

Comment: Are you wanting the total of the Attendances for the items that match?

Comment: I don't think you gain anything by projecting to an anonymous object containing the item itself: item => new { value = item }.  You can skip that step and remove the .value along the way

Comment: could you us what is the problem you were having with your statement above?  Possibly create some test data.  You look fairly close to me.  Here's a good place to visit now and then when LINQ isn't going right for you -- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vcsharp/aa336746

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Count()` method:

```
return studentInfoList
    .Where(item => item.StudentName.Equals(name) 
          && item.StudentID.Equals(id))
    .Select(item => item.Attendance.Count());
```

---

```
// find student using conditions, suppose it may be only one
var student = studentInfoList
    .SingleOrDefault(item => item.StudentName.Equals(name)
        && item.StudentID.Equals(id));
// found
if (student != null)
{
    return student.Attendance;
}
else
{
    // not found
}
```

Comment: I think attendance is a property and not an enumeration...?

Comment: @Greg, @James, Attendance it's property, right. Is it enumeration or not?

Answer (score 1):

I would try this

```
return studentInfoList.First(s => s.Name == name && s.StudentId == id).Attendance
```

Why is studentId not enough to locate a student?

Comment: Good question on ID, Keep in my First() throws though if not found.  Use FirstOrDefault() instead possibly.

Answer (score 1):

If you are talking the Attendance property of the item found, you just need:

```
var count = studentInfoList
    .Where(item => item.StudentName.Equals(name) && item.StudentID.Equals(id))
    .Select(item => item.Attendance).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: If you want to assume student not found is zero attendance, this works, if you want to do something special if student not found, @Heinzi has a better one where you pull the student, and then get the attendance if not null.

Comment: sorry i still had your value. in there from your projection.

Comment: Fixed now, also what is your data set and what are you searching for?

Answer (score 1):

Your data structure is hard to understand, but I've tried to simplify it and clean up.

```
return studentInfoList
    .Single(si => si.StudentName == name || si.StudentID == id)
    .Attendance;
```

I've assumed you only need the name or the id to find a student, not both. Also that Attendance is an integer, not an array. And that you need to make sure it is only for a single student, and if the student isn't found it should throw an exception.

Comment: Might want to give your assumption is that there always exists one and always one, and the condition should be `&&` not `||`

Comment: @Greg it will go through the list to make sure only 1 item fits the condition, otherwise throw an exception.

Answer (score 1):

```
// return the student with the given name and ID or null, if it cannot be found
StudentInfo student =
    studentInfoList.Where(item => item.StudentName == name 
                                   && item.StudentID == id).SingleOrDefault();

if (student == null) {
    // student not found
} else {
    return student.Attendance;
}
```